# Why client cannot connect to the Java Websocket server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I am learning websockets with Spring 5. I use [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-reactive-websockets). But when I try to connect to websocket via JavaScript I have the folowing error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/event-emitter' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

When I try to connect to websocket via Java I have the folowing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientException: HTTP request failed with code: 404.
Failing URI: /event-emitter
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1185)
```

My *ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.java*:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication {

@Autowired
private ReactiveWebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public HandlerMapping webSocketHandlerMapping() {
    Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/event-emitter", webSocketHandler);

    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(1);
    handlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);
    return handlerMapping;
}
@Bean
public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
    return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
}
}
```

*ReactiveWebSocketHandler.java*:

```
@Component
public class ReactiveWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

private static final ObjectMapper json = new ObjectMapper();

private Flux<String> eventFlux = Flux.generate(sink -> {
    EventTwo event = new EventTwo(Double.toString(Math.random()), new Date().toString());
    try {
        sink.next(json.writeValueAsString(event));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        sink.error(e);
    }
});
private Flux<String> intervalFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000L))
        .zipWith(eventFlux, (time, event) -> event);

@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
    return webSocketSession.send(intervalFlux
            .map(webSocketSession::textMessage))
            .and(webSocketSession.receive()
                    .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                    .log());
}
}
```

JavaScript which try to connect to websocket:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../res/messages.css';
class Messages extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {messages: []};
}

getInitialState(){
    return { messages : [] }
}

componentDidMount() {
    var clientWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/event-emitter");
    clientWebSocket.onopen = function() {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onopen", clientWebSocket);
        console.log("clientWebSocket.readyState", "websocketstatus");
        clientWebSocket.send("event-me-from-browser");
    }
    clientWebSocket.onclose = function(error) {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onclose", clientWebSocket, error);
    }
    clientWebSocket.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onerror", clientWebSocket, error);
    }
    clientWebSocket.onmessage = function(error) {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onmessage", clientWebSocket, error);
        this.setState({
                        messages : this.state.messages.concat([ new Date() ])
                    })
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div><ul>{ this.state.messages.map( (msg, idx) => <li key={'msg-' + idx }>{ msg }</li> )}</ul></div>
    )
}
}
```

Should there be additional configuration of websockets in Java side\Spring? Why client cannot connect to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I used the configurations from another [guide](http://blog.monkey.codes/how-to-build-a-chat-app-using-webflux-websockets-react/).

I created [ChatSocketHandler.java](https://github.com/monkey-codes/java-reactive-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/codes/monkey/reactivechat/ChatSocketHandler.java), [ReactiveChatApplication.java](https://github.com/monkey-codes/java-reactive-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/codes/monkey/reactivechat/ReactiveChatApplication.java) without *userStats()*.

My *Event.java*:

```
@Data
public class Event {
private String eventId;
private String eventDt;

public Event() {
}

public Event(String eventId, String eventDt) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
    this.eventDt = eventDt;
}

public String getEventId() {
    return eventId;
}

public void setEventId(String eventId) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
}

public String getEventDt() {
    return eventDt;
}

public void setEventDt(String eventDt) {
    this.eventDt = eventDt;
}
}
```

And my JavaScript file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../res/messages.css';
const client = require('../client');

class Messages extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {messages: []};{messages: []};
}

getInitialState(){
    return { messages : [] }
}

updateMessages(msg){
    this.setState({
        messages : this.state.messages.concat([ msg ])
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    var clientWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/websocket/chat");
    clientWebSocket.onopen = function() {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onopen", clientWebSocket);
        console.log("clientWebSocket.readyState", "websocketstatus");
        clientWebSocket.send("event-me-from-browser");
    }
    clientWebSocket.onclose = function(error) {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onclose", clientWebSocket, error);
    }
    clientWebSocket.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onerror", clientWebSocket, error);
    }
    var tmpMsg;
    var _this = this;
    clientWebSocket.onmessage = function(dataFromServer) {
        console.log("clientWebSocket.onmessage", clientWebSocket, dataFromServer);
        var date =  new Date() ;
        tmpMsg =  dataFromServer;
        _this.updateMessages(tmpMsg);
    }

}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{ this.state.messages.map( (msg) =>
                <li>{ JSON.parse(msg.data).eventDt }</li> )}
            </ul>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add WebSocketHandlerAdapter class on context(@Bean)? if not, try to add WebSocketHandlerAdapter class on context.

```
private final WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

@Bean
public HandlerMapping webSocketHandlerMapping() {
    Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/event-emitter", webSocketHandler);

    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(1);
    handlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);
    return handlerMapping;
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
    return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
}
```